# Выбор видимой области картинки, как на youtube?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть уже готовый скрипт загрузки изображения и создание миниатюры на php. При выборе картинки с компа, вывод происходит прямиком в нужный блок div. 

Нужно сделать такую штуку: 
При зажатии и переносе мышки вниз-вверх картинка меняла background-position, тем самым пользователь мог выбрать ту область, которую показать в div. Конечно же нужно еще сделать так, чтобы картинка не двигалась по горизонтальной плоскости и по вертикале исходя их размера самой картинки, дабы не выводился задний фон и картинка не съезжала за границы div.

**Код JavaScript + jquery**

```
function filter(id,id2){
    var input = $("#image"+id)[0],
        obl = document.getElementById('bk-cover'+id),
        fon = document.getElementById(id2),
        bt = document.getElementById("load-button"+id);
    if ( input.files && input.files[0] ) {
        if ( input.files[0].type.match('gif|png|jpg|jpeg') ) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
            filesize = input.files[0].size;
                if(filesize <= 10000000){
            obl.style.backgroundImage='url('+ e.target.result +')';
            fon.style.backgroundImage='url('+ e.target.result +')';
            bt.disabled = false;
                }
          }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        } else alert('Загружать можно только картинки в форматах jpg, png, gif');
    } else alert('Что-то пошло не так. Попробуйте снова.');
};
```

[image: Пример страницы]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Image cropper plugin](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper)

Я думаю это поможет